# How to use a video device in a lxd container?

Tags: lxc, lxd

I would like to use the host video device (`/dev/video0` for instance) in a [`lxd` container](https://www.stgraber.org/2016/03/11/lxd-2-0-introduction-to-lxd-112/).

There is [information](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/doc/configuration.md#devices-configuration) about how to configure devices in `lxd` but it only mentions char and block devices (which `/dev/video0` is not, right?).

**Is it therefore possible to use the host vodeo device in a container?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use a host video device in a LXD container.

I have verified it with an USB webcam attached to the host. The webcam can be added to the container as follows:

```
lxc config device add my-container video0 unix-char path=/dev/video0
```

After a restart of the container the /dev/video0 device was accessible in the container.

At least a webcam works as a character device. I have not checked whether this also applies to other video devices.

There was no need to configure the /dev/bus/usb/00? in the container. It seems that LXD 2.5 maps them by default.

Comment: Thanks. In the meantime I moved to `systemd-nspawn` (which uses `systemd` and it allows me to have consistent calls) so I believe you blindly :)